# Waterline: How to perform IN queries if attribute is a collection?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

In the [docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/ORM/Querylanguage.md) of waterline it is stated that this is the way to perform a IN query on a model:

```
Model.find({
  name : ['Walter', 'Skyler']
});
```

And this the way to perform an OR query on a model:

```
Model.find({
  or : [
    { name: 'walter' },
    { occupation: 'teacher' }
  ]
})
```

My problem now is that i need a combination of those two, and to make it even more complicated, one of the attributes i have to use is a collection.

So what i tried is this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Product.find({
  or : [
    { createdBy: userIds },
    { likes: userIds }
  ]
})
```

Note: userIds is an array of id's from a user model.

The (simplified) product model looks likes this:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: 'string',
        description: 'string',
        createdBy: {
            model: 'User'
        },
        brand:  {
            model: 'Brand',
        },
        likes: {
            collection: 'User',
        }
    }
}
```

The query works when I only include createdBy, so it seems to be a problem with the collection attribute.
Is this somehow possible?
Thank you for your input.

**UPDATE:**

I think this is only possible with native() queries.
The way I understand it something like this should work.

```
Product.native(function(err, products){
                        if(err) return res.serverError(err);

                        products.find({"likes": { $elemMatch: { _id: { $in: userIds}}}}).toArray(function(err, results){
                            if (err){
                                console.log('ERROR', err);
                            } 
                            else {
                                console.log("found products: " + results.length);
                                console.log(results);
                                return res.ok(results);
                            } 
                        });
                    });
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't. The returned `results` is always an empty array.

Comment: I don't think you can do that through the default waterline `find()`. You can probably use `.native()` though, which allows you to perform a raw mongo query. http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native

Comment: Hello @Fissio, I am already on that track. I think it should be possible using `native()` but haven't found a solution yet.

Check my edited question to see how i try to get it work.